# WPF How does implement right mouse popup manu in TreeView

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm having trouble learning WPF MVVM, and the current problem is with the TreeView

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VrZt.png)
when i try to take manu in here. but view can't show manu view, so what can i do
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVQcJ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09PE5.png)

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of an image.